# ¿Como hacer notificaciones en laravel 8 con condiciones especificas?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, notification

Hola a todos estoy usando el sistema de notificaciones de laravel8: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#introduction, los tutoriales que he visto de este sistema explican como crear una notificación a partir de la creación de cierto registro, pero lo que intento es distinto, tengo una tabla products e intento que se cree una notificación cuando la fecha de vencimiento de un registro de la tabla products esté a menos de 30 días de vencerse, este es el código que uso en mi controlador principal.

```
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $product = Product::whereRaw(' DATEDIFF(due_date, ? ) < ?', [$date, 30])->get();
    User::all()->each(function(User $user) use ($product){
        $user->notify(new ProductsNotification($product));
    });
```

Uso carbon para obtener la fecha de hoy, luego con un datediff comparo las dos fechas para ver si tienen menos de 30 dias de separación, luego busco a todos los usuarios y envio la notificación.

El archivo de notificación que creé está de esta forma.(también creé la tabla correspondiente)

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable; 
class ProductsNotification extends Notification
{
  use Queueable;
  use Notifiable;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Product $product)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}
/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'code' => $this->product->code,
        'name' => $this->product->name,
        'due_date' => $this->product->due_date,
        'description' => $this->product->description

    ];
}
}
```

La consulta de  $product funciona bien, pero la integración del código no funciona ya que me genera este error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Notifications\ProductsNotification::__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\Product, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given, called in C:\laragon\www\tiendaslaravel\app\Http\Controllers\DashboardController.php on line 38
```

Tengo 2 preguntas: ¿cual es el error en el código? y ¿de que manera puedo hacer que este código se esté ejecutando cada cierto tiempo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De la manera en que lo haces generas una notificación para cada usuario y en el constructor de la notificación estas mandando todos los productos en una colección, siendo que debes mandarlo uno por uno, te sugiero estos cambios.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification; 

$date = now()->addDays(30);
$users = User::all();
Product::where('due_date, '<', $date)->get()->each(function($product) use ($users) {
    Notification::send($users, new ProductsNotification($product));
});
```

Comment: funcionó, muchas gracias